# How to scrape contents of this page with Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Can someone please tell me how to scrape the data (Names & Numbers) from this page using Scrapy. The data is dynamically loaded. But nothing comes in Network tab. In which case is Network tab useful? I am a beginner.
URL: https://www.icab.es/es/servicios-a-la-ciudadania/necesito-un-abogado/buscador-de-profesionales/?extraSearch=false&probono=false

Answer (score 1):

If you check Network tab you'll find a `POST` request to `https://www.icab.es/rest/icab-api/collegiates`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Earlier I wasn't getting anything in Network Tab due to some wrong developer tools settings.